# Scroll to Top jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a super simple Scroll to top button.

It works but it's appending the button to the body every time when i scroll.

I would like to append it only once and fade it in and if you click it you will be scrolled back to the top off the page and it will fadeout.

The functionality is working but its appending it to the page in an loop.

I know it's a simple bug but, I can't figure it out.

My code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
    var to_top = '<a class="back-to-top" href="#"></a>';

    if (scrollPosition >= 500) {
        $("body").append(to_top);
        $('.back-to-top').fadeIn(1600);
    } else {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeOut(800);
    }

    $( ".back-to-top" ).on( "click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Create the button on doc ready instead of scroll. Hide it at first, and show when needed during scrolling. You can also create the button in the html and just hide it. when scrolling, show it when needed

Comment: @Huangism Thanks that worked wonderfully. Now that you said it was obvious :D.

Comment: It's also a good idea to check if the button is visible or not before fading in or out so it does not need to fade in/out when it doesn't need to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're telling it to append the  every time the scroll event is fired, so check if it exists first, see if it works out for you.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
  var toTops = $('.back-to-top'); // get jQ object once
      if (scrollPosition >= 500) {
        if (!toTops.length){ // if no elems

            // create one
            var $to_top = $('<a class="back-to-top" href="#"></a>');
            $to_top.on( "click", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
            });

            // then attach it
            $("body").append($to_top);
        } else { 

           // if elems exist, fade them in
           toTops.fadeIn(1600);
        }

      } else {
        toTops.fadeOut(800);
      }


});
```

Comment: I think you have the checking backwards, it reads `if (toTops.length)` then attach button else fade out

Comment: @Likwid_T The fadeIn and Out works but if i click the button it does not scroll to the top off the page at the moment.

Comment: Because I appended the object and not the jQuery object which I attached the event listener to...Try that now...not sharp this afternoon

Answer (score 0):

You should create button once and then hide/show it.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var to_top = $('<a class="back-to-top" href="#"></a>'),
    visible = false;
    to_top.appendTo('body').hide();

    $( ".back-to-top" ).on( "click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 500)
            if(!visible){
                to_top.stop(true,false).fadeIn(1600);
                visible = true;
            }
        else
            if(visible){
                to_top.stop(true,false).fadeOut(800);
                visible = false;
            }
    });
});
```